# Check image if portrait or landscape?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, minimagick

I have a Cropping image system which I want only Portrait images to be sent to.
The thing is I don't know how to validate that images are Portraits or Landscapes before sending them to one place or another.

I thought about Mini Magick, maybe something like this? (Wont work)

#### Photo model

```
  def validate_image_size
    image = MiniMagick::Image.open(photo.path)
     if image[:height] > image[:width]
      #send the image to this place
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok the validator is working now.

```
  def validate_image_size
    image = MiniMagick::Image.open(photo.path)
     if image[:height] > image[:width]
      #send the image to this place
    end
  end
```

Comment: Validation is working, but I'm getting a strange error:

Errno::ENOENT in PhotosController#create
No such file or directory -